# Where do you add the merchants email address to the Magento back-end

Tags: magento

Where do you add the merchants email address to the Magento back-end so they can get automatically notified when someone makes a purchase.

Comment: Did you resolve this Jonathan?

Comment: Yes yes. sorry, it completely slipped my mind to check the "accept answer" button. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automatically send a copy of the `Sales Email` to another address, if this is what you mean. Go to `System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails` and look in the `Order` tab.

You can then fill in the `Send Order Email Copy To` option.

Copies of other emails can be set up to be sent to alternative email addresses here too.

Comment: We put the test email address in all fields from the sales email page and it's still not sending what the person ordered (for our test orders).

Comment: but you are getting the primary email?

Comment: We aren't getting any Magento emails after an order is placed. We are using authorize.net as a payment gateway and are only getting those emails. Unfortunately authorize doesn't state what product was purchased, just the amount that was payed.

Comment: Ok, this is a completely different problem and one you really should have made clear in your original question. You need to give considerably more information to solve this. Does the server even have functioning capability?

Comment: Are you getting _any_ emails from magento at all?